# Mongoose- Search/Filter data from array into another array with the specific items

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have an mongoDB object like

```
{   
    "courseName" : "AI",
    "user" : ObjectId("6087dc4c2ba7a828363c9fca"),
    "questions" : [ 
        { 
             "optionsSet" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : "A",
                },
                {
                    "value" : "B",
                }
             ],
            "topics" : ["b", "c", "a"],
            "createdAt" : "2021-07-07T18:41:18.971Z"
        }, 
        {
           "optionsSet" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : "C",
                },
                {
                    "value" : "D",
                }
             ],
            "topics" : ["c"],
            "createdAt" : "2021-08-07T18:41:18.971Z
        },
        {
            "optionsSet" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : "CC",
                },
                {
                    "value" : "DD",
                }
             ],
            "topics" : ["b"],
            "createdAt" : "2021-08-07T18:41:30.971Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sometime I have to use only match the `courseName` and `user` only.

Another time I have to query with the `courseName` `user`  and `topics`
where topics which at least match one topic. How can i handle this process?

When I pass input as `courseName`, `user` and topics `["b"]`. I deselected `user` and `optionsSet` in return output. My expected out put will be :

```
{
    "courseName" : "AI",
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "topics" : ["b", "c", "a"],
        }, 
        {
            "topics" : ["b"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use dot notation `{ "questions.topics": "a" }`

Comment: My input will be array. like ["a", "b"]

Comment: You can use $in operator `{ "questions.topics": { "$in": ["a", "b"] } }`

Comment: I updated my question, turivishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation query,

- `$match` to check your condition using `$in` operator
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `questions` and check if topics having any input search `topics`
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `topics` and search for `topics`

```
let p = YourSchema.aggregate();

// courseName
if (req.body.courseName) p.match({ courseName: req.body.courseName });

// user
if (req.body.user) p.match({ user: req.body.user });

// topics
if (req.body.topics) {
  p.match({ "questions.topics": { $in: req.body.topics } });

  p.addFields({
    questions: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$questions",
        cond: {
          $ne: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$this.topics",
                cond: { $in: ["$$this", req.body.topics] }
              }
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

let result = await p.exec();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WkElZti6vt)

Comment: Can i query without using the aggregation framework?I have to match also another  fields. I updated my question. Please do not mind 
turivishal.

Comment: I have updated the answer with mongoose aggregation pipeline builder.

Comment: You use `YourSchema` is database model or only the schema? I got an empty array as output.

Comment: Its mongoose database schema model.

Comment: Can you do another help?. I used which elements i want to retrieve/selects in normal aggregation. But In this way i do not want select user as return object. How can i do this?

Comment: Do I have to use `$project`?

Comment: aggregation will always return an array, even if its single document, you can select it from zeroth element `result[0]`.

Comment: I updated my question.Here i do not want to return `optionsSet` and `user`. Can you help another?

Comment: use `p.project()` stage, please don't update your question everytime, its ok 1/2 time otherwise people will frustrate and will not answer your question, add all details when you ask new question, you can ask new question.

Comment: If you do not mind this is my other question. Basically this is the part of my query. So I do not create another question. When I retrieve the questions I want to sort the questions by date. I updated my question. @turivishal